# Rails Active Model Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I think what I'm trying to accomplish is multi table inheritance but I'm not sure how to properly implement it.

I want to start with a base class `Device` that will contain all the common fields such as name and enabled.

```
class Device
  # in app/models
  # Fields
  #   String name
  #   boolean enabled
end
```

I then want to create abstract classes for the different device types such as `Light` that inherits from `Device`

```
class Light < ActiveRecord:Base
  # in app/models
  # Fields
  #  String type

  include Device

  def on
    raise NotImplementedError
  end

  def off
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

I then will have classes for specific devices such as `X10Light` and `ZWaveLight` that will define the specifics for each device and implement the abstract methods.

```
class X10Light < Light
  # in app/models
  # Fields
  #   String serial_number

  def on
    # fully implemented on method
  end

  def off
    # fully implemented off method
  end
end
```

My goal would then be to use it like the following

```
light1 = X10Light.new
light1.serial_number = "x1"
light1.save

light2 = ZWaveLight.new
light2.serial_number = "z1"
light2.save

all_lights = Light.all
all_lights.each do |light|
  light.off
end
```

I think the way I have things planned out this is possible, but I think have some of the implementation incorrect.  I'd appreciate any help ironing out the details on this. Thanks!

Comment: In ruby, don't do ` def on
    raise NotImplementedError
  end` --- instead, have your class not `respond_to :on`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Single Table Inheritance, you will need to create a model `Device` which will hold all your fields plus a reserved column named `type`, where rails will store the class name of the concrete instance.

```
rails g model Device type:string ... other fields (ie columns for device, light, x10light) ...

class Device < ActiveRecord:Base
  ...
end

class Light < Device
  ...
end

class X10Light < Light
  ...
end
```

The downside of using STI is that you end up with a table which has all the columns of the tree of your inheritance.

Comment: On behalf of [Niels-b](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1690765/niels-b): Your models will be automatically scoped meaning that when you do e.g. Light.all, Rails will fire a SQL query for records in the devices table where type equals light. Keep in mind that subclasses will not be found. So Light.all will not include any X10Light's.

Comment: Actually, I have to correct myself. The missing subclasses are only a problem in development. In production, Rails preloads all classes and builds a nice family tree, so a query for Light.all, would actually build a where clause that queries for both light and x10light.